# Is there a automatic solution for the room seperator function?

Tags: revit

Currently I am working on a project to transform a BIM file of a building into 3D spaces of rooms. Unfortunately, it is not working out as planned. The doors and windows which are in this IFC file are missing the checkbox "Room Bounding". Because of this I am not able to create rooms for the reason that windows and doors are seen as holes. How do I add the option "Room bounding checkbox" to the Doors and windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Revit, doors and windows are hosted by walls and form part of the walls they are hosted by. Therefore, wherever you have a door or window, you also have a wall hosting it, and thus a room separator. So where is the problem?

Anyway, if there is a problem with any of this, you can always add room separator lines in addition to the walls, doors and windows, can't you?

Cf. the Revit online help [About Room Separation Lines](https://help.autodesk.com/view/RVT/2020/ENU/?guid=GUID-6B8BDC71-D0A4-4ABA-8561-34F7AD6BAB55).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried to add room seperator lines in addition to the walls, doors and windows. This worked. However I am interested in automating this for the reason that my BIM file is to large to do everything by hand. Is there any function I can use? Or write a piece of code?

Comment: Yes, you could certainly write code to add room separator lines in addition to all walls, doors and windows. for walls, it is especially easy, since you can ask the wall for its location line (with an underlying geometry `Curve`) and use that to define the room separator line. for doors and windows it might be a little bit more complicated. however, they should not be needed, since the walls hosting them should take care of covering those openings.